# Remove empty paragraphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm importing an RSS feed which has a series of empty paragraphs "`<p> </p>`".

I am using gsub however it's not stripping the elements from the document:

`document.gsub(/<p>\s*<\/p>/,"")` or `gsub(/<p> <\/p>/,"")`

Is there an alternative method or a mistake in the above?

The below appears to work?

```
gsub(/<p>.<\/p>/,"")
```

Comment: `document.gsub(/<p>\s*<\/p>/,"")` works fine for your sample input. Could you add a failing test case?

Comment: Hint: For a simple way to build and test regex, use rubular.com

Comment: . Any single character, seems to work

Comment: Maybe you miss something as simple as `document = document.gsub(/<p>\s*<\/p>/,"")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct regex like in example:

```
>> document = "<p>\n\n\n   \n</p>aaa<p>  </p>bbb"                       
=> "<p>\n\n\n   \n</p>aaa<p>  </p>bbb"                                  
>> document.gsub(/<p>[\s$]*<\/p>/, '')                                  
=> "aaabbb"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the paragraph elements in your RSS feed uses `id` and `classes` try [this](http://rubular.com/r/7Mw82cMeTw):

```
gsub(/\<p(\s((class)|(id))=[\'\"][A-z0-9\s]+[\'\"]\s*)*\>\s*\<\/p\>/,"")
```